# PowerShell script to update tags in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to update some legacy resource tags in our Azure environment. I need to preserve these resources' tags and just update one of them but this simple task on 100s of resources is becoming a headache for me. PowerShell will not overwrite an existing tag with a new value easily at all so I created what I hoped was a script to create a variable for the current tags, omitting the one needed updating, removing all tags applied, adding the new tag and value to the stored tags variable then applying them to all the resources with this incorrect tag value. Here is my code:

```
$r = (Get-AzResource -Tag @{Environment="Non-Prodd"}).Name
$tags = (Get-AzResource -Name $r).Tags | Where {$_.Key -ne 'Environment'}
Get-AzResource -resourcename $r | Set-AzResource -Tag @{} 
$tags += @{Environment="Non-Prod"} 
Get-AzResource -resourcename $r | Set-AzResource -Tag $tags -Force
```

I use "Non-Prod" as an example for the value that needs updated. The $tags variable code does not exclude the Environment tag in its output and that is my biggest issue. Reapplying the tags from the stored variable barks at me about "Environment" still being applied.

If I simply run:

```
(Get-AzResource -Name $r).Tags | Where {$_.Key -ne 'Environment'}
```

The omitted tag is still in the list.

I am also open to any other ways to accomplish my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do:

```
$tags = (Get-AzResource -Name $r).Tags
$tags.environment = value
Get-AzResource -resourcename $r | Set-AzResource -Tag $tags -Force
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Comment: One last question. It seems that this script works if only one resource has the incorrect tag name. If I set another resource with the incorrect tag and run the script, it errors out about $r not being a supported parameter. The tags I am wanting to update are on about 50 resources.

Comment: you must put the code into foreach loop, but I guess you already know it