# How do you update many azure tags simultaneously?

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I seem to be able to find solutions for updating each resource tag individually. But I can't find out how to do many tags at the same time. Help?

1. [Update-aztag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/update-aztag?view=azps-7.0.0)
2. [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tags)

Comment: Did you see this post?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57929322/powershell-script-to-update-tags-in-azure
or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57962737/update-azure-resource-tags-for-multiple-resources

Comment: These posts are pointing to an iteration through a for loop to apply tags to each resource. I am looking for a fix to apply them to several resources simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

The `Update-AzTag` cmdlet with a ResourceId selectively updates the set of tags on a resource or subscription. This operation allows replacing, merging or selectively deleting tags on the specified resource or subscription.

- The 'replace' option replaces the entire set of existing tags with a
  new set.
- The 'merge' option allows adding tags with new names and
  updating the values of tags with existing names.
- The 'delete' option
  allows selectively deleting tags based on given names or name/value
  pairs.

1.If you **want to replace the tags for all the resource** in the subscription you can use the below PowerShell script.

```html
    connect-azaccount
    $replacedTags= @{"key1"="value1"; "key3"="value3"}
    $resourcelist= Get-AzResource
    foreach($item in $resourcelist){
        Update-Aztag -ResourceId $item.ResourceId -Tag $replacedTags -Operation Replace
    }
```

**Here is the sample Output for reference:**

[image]

2.If you **want to replace a specific tag** you can refer the below PowerShell script.

```
$replacedTags= @{"key3"="value3"}
$resourcelist= Get-AzResource

foreach($item in $resourcelist){
    
    $existtags=(Get-AzTag -ResourceId $item.ResourceId)
    if(($existtags.Properties.TagsProperty.Values -contains 'value1') -and ( $existtags.Properties.TagsProperty.Keys -contains 'key1'))
    {
        Update-Aztag -ResourceId $item.ResourceId -Tag $replacedTags -Operation Replace
    }
}
```

**Here is the sample Output for reference:**

[image]

3.If you **want to merge a specific tags** you can refer the below PowerShell script.

```
$mergedTags=@{"key2"="value2"; "key3"="value3"}
$resourcelist= Get-AzResource
foreach($item in $resourcelist){
    
    $existtags=(Get-AzTag -ResourceId $item.ResourceId)
    if(($existtags.Properties.TagsProperty.Values -contains 'key1') -and ( $existtags.Properties.TagsProperty.Keys -contains 'value1'))
    {
        Update-AzTag -ResourceId $item.ResourceId -Tag $mergedTags -Operation Merge
    }
}
```

**Here is the sample output for reference :**
[image]

Comment: thanks but these are for selective resources, the question is how do you update them in parallel? Every solution I find results in an update for each resource, which takes forever for relatively large tenants.

Comment: if you are using Windows PowerShell 5.1 you want to execute the task in parallel would suggested to use ``ForEach -Parallel`` this should be construct in Windows Powershell workflow . Here is the reference [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_foreach-parallel?view=powershell-5.1)  for more information. 
We have tested this in our local environment which is working fine here is the screenshot for reference https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvmQu.png

Comment: If you are using Powershell7 you can use ``Foreach-object -parallel`` to execute job in parallel here is the reference documentation.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/

Answer (score 0):

1. Find **id's** of **type** resources which you want to update tags

   - You can run query in **"Azure Resource Graph Explorer"**

     `resources| where type contains "microsoft.sql"|project ['id']`

     [image]
2. Copy Paste list of **Id's** in file.txt or you can download CSV and pass to Script (We are going to read this file line by line)
3. Open **Azure CLI**
4. Drag and drop your **file.txt** and PowerShell script in **Azure CLI**

   [image]
5. Run PowerShell Script by issuing **"./updateResourceTagsIterate.ps1"**

**updateResourceTagsIterate.ps1**

```
$tags = @{"Team"="Compliance"; "Environment"="Production"}
 foreach($line in Get-Content .\file.txt) {
    if($line -match $regex){
        write-host $line
        Update-AzTag -ResourceId $line -Tag $tags -Operation Merge
    }
}
```

You can refer [official link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-resources?tabs=json) from Microsoft for Azure CLI commands to update tags